# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to figure out why I get this error. My code is as follows:

```
 ArrayList lowestQuant = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < aRes1.size(); i++) {
        int var = Math.min(casesQuant.get(i), mainboardQuant.get(i));
        int var2 = Math.min(var, cpuQuant.get(i));
        int var3 = Math.min(var2, ramQuant.get(i));
        int var4 = Math.min(var3, graphicsQuant.get(i));
        lowestQuant.add(var4);
        System.out.println(aRes1.get(i) +" quantity: "+lowestQuant.get(i));
    }
```

`aRes1` is an Array List of computer systems with a length of 8 computer systems.

I need to find the component with the lowest quantity in every computer system, hence the `Math.min` and all the `ArrayList-index` look-ups.
This code should provide the component with the lowest quantity and it does! But somehow it stops before reaching the 8th computer system. It works perfectly with the first `7`.
Can anyone tell me what the problem is?
I've looked a lot of these errors up and tried to set `i=1` and `.size()-1/+1` nothing helps.

Thanks in advance!
Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
            at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
            at databasen.Database.ComputerSystems(Database.java:242)
            at databasen.Database.menuLVL1(Database.java:70)
            at databasen.Database.mainMenu(Database.java:61)
            at databasen.Database.main(Database.java:37)
    Java Result: 1
```

To clarify : All the array lists used are of the same length because they are made from a database. Here are some more code so you can see how the array lists are made ::

```
ArrayList aRes1 = new ArrayList();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT catchyname FROM computersystems");
        System.out.printf("Computer sytems:\n");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String answer = rs.getString("catchyname");
            aRes1.add(answer);
        }

        // Cases
        ArrayList aRes2 = new ArrayList();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT cases FROM computersystems");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String answer = rs.getString("cases");
            aRes2.add(answer);
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> casesQuant = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0;i<aRes2.size();i++){
            ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT currentquantity FROM components "
                    + "WHERE name ="+"'"+aRes2.get(i)+"'");
            while (rs2.next()) {
                int answer2 = rs2.getInt("currentquantity");
                casesQuant.add(answer2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Java is 0 indexed so the last valid cell in a Java array is the `size - 1`. The eighth value is in the cell 7.

Comment: Which line is 242? It sounds like the lists don't all have the same size...

Comment: Whitch are line number 547 , 322 ,242 ??

Comment: Try System.out.println("" + (i+1) + ": " + aRes1.get(i) +" quantity: "+lowestQuant.get(i)); and you should see it is evaluating all 8.

Comment: 547 and 322 are inside the Java packages as it also says.
The line, 242, are the "for (int i = 0; i < aRes1.size(); i++) {"

I know that the lists are all the same size

Comment: That doesn't work, Justin, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The error *can't* be on the `for` statement - you don't access any listitem there. Please double check which line is #242.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, #242 is
"int var = Math.min(casesQuant.get(i), mainboardQuant.get(i));"

Comment: The problem occurs at one of these 2 get functions...So double check
casesQuant, mainboardQuant ....

Comment: I edited my post so you can now see how the array lists are created. It is not possible that they are not the same size as they are made from a database.

Comment: I found the error! Thanks for all the suggestions! The mistake was in a name in the database. It couldn't compare the names. And how should you all have know that! But again, thanks for all your help! Without it I would never have double checked the database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any one of the Array Lists has 7 elements . Try checking line number 547 and 322 .  you will get an idea which one .

Comment: The way I have created the array lists used above will give them the same length as the aRes1.

Answer (score 1):

Java starts at index 0 and goes up.  A size of 7 means an index of 6.
Change:
    (int i = 0; i < aRes1.size(); i++)
To:
    (int i = 0; i < aRes1.size()-1; i++)
Subtracting one will fix the problem.

Comment: It does not, believe me I have tried. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @AndreasDam Yes it does.  However, the for loop provided by Ryan will skip the last element. It should be `i < aRes1.size()`

Comment: @Ryan, I suggest removing "Change: ..." as it really isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

> line 242 is "`int var = Math.min(casesQuant.get(i), mainboardQuant.get(i));`"

Add the following line before that one:

```
System.out.printf("Expected: #s, Cases: #s, Mainboards: #s#n", aRes1.size(), 
      casesQuant.get(i), mainboardQuant.get(i));
```

One number should be less then the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

you are working with multiple arrays that don't all have the same size, but using an index from one array on all of the arrays. this is the cause of the exception.